# Resize picturebox and maintain aspect ratio (1:1) vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a picturebox that I am resizing and I need it to maintain an aspect ratio of 1:1. Basically have both the width and height be the same as the user is resizing. The resizing works fine, but the aspect ratio does not maintain. How could I change this to include maintaining aspect ratio?

This is what is called when the control is resized

```
    Private Sub pbsMouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If mouseOnHandle Then
        ReleaseCapture()
        SendMessage(activeControl.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, CInt(DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).Tag), 0)
        If GetCapture = 0 Then mouseOnHandle = False
        Application.DoEvents()
    End If
End Sub
```

ReleaseCapture()

```
    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function ReleaseCapture() As Boolean
End Function
```

Contstants and function

```
    Public Declare Function GetCapture Lib "user32" Alias "GetCapture" () As Integer

Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &HA1
```

Comment: The size of the displayed image has little to do with the size (or ratio) of the picturebox.  Also, 1:1 means a square...which is probably not what you mean

Comment: You can set the [`SizeMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx) of the `PictureBox` to `Zoom`. This way, by changing the size of the `PictureBox`, the size of the image is increased or decreased maintaining the size ratio.

Comment: I have the picturebox to be set to stretch, so that the whole image fits inside. And I do mean 1:1. I am resizing a QR code, which should be a square

Comment: Based on your specs, you don't want stretch then.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear with my question. I want the actual picturebox control's aspect ratio to be maintained. So, if a user resizes it, its width and height will both increase/decrease. I need the whole QR code to be displayed in the picture box, so I chose stretch. I'm not sure how changing the SizeMode would help with this?

Comment: Are you changing the size of the picturebox directly or is it sizing based on the control it resides in? If you're sizing it directly from code then you just make sure that your width and height are the same. If you're sizing it based on the parent then you'll need to take a copy of the size prior to resizing then on resize work out whether you've got bigger or smaller and which axis has the biggest change then set the width and height based on that.

Comment: Give us all the code that resizes your PictureBox.

Comment: Check edited post. I have drag handles that appear on my control when a user clicks it. That code is called when the drag handle is moved, which causes the control to resize

Comment: Right.  We don't see that code.  The point of asking for that code is so we can duplicate the problem on our machines.

Comment: Gotcha. I solved it myself

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding this function to the resize event of the control

```
    Private Sub maintainAspectRatio()
    Dim width As Integer = activeControl.Width
    Dim height As Integer = activeControl.Height

    If width > height Then
        activeControl.Height = activeControl.Width
    ElseIf height > width Then
        activeControl.Width = activeControl.Height
    End If
End Sub
```

This solved the issue for me